# wix ExitDialog Conditions

Tags: wix

I have a Custom Action that launches an app from the ExitDialog Dialog, if the user ticks the check box that is. At any rate, my app has three features and the option to launch this app should only appear if one of the features has been installed.

I have the following code:

```
<Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="DoAction" Value="RCTPI" >


            <![CDATA[LAUNCHUPONEXIT AND &WindowsService=3 AND NOT INSTALLED]]>
            </Publish>

        <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Launch Config Tool" > </Property>
```

I would have expected that the *&WindowsService=3* meant that only if the WindowsService feature was selected to be installed, would the condition be met. However it appears regardless of what features are selected to be installed.

Any ideas?

TIA

YM

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that by the moment ExitDialog is displayed, the referenced feature is already installed. Hence, you should probably use install state syntax instead of install action, i.e. `!WindowsService=3`. Never tried it myself though...

Comment: that makes no difference, I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

I've actually ended up doing an old fashioned custom action, I've spent enough time as it is on this.

```
<Custom Action="RCTPI" Before="InstallFinalize"><![CDATA[&WindowsService=3 and NOT INSTALLED]]></Custom>
```